# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on swift

Tags: swift

I am running into this issue on this part of the code with SwiftMoment
https://github.com/akosma/SwiftMoment

```
public func moment(_ timetoken: Int64) -> Moment {
  return moment(Int(timetoken / 10000))
}
```

I am not sure why it's happenning. If you have any insights, feel free to share.
Thanks!

[image]

here is the timetoken value: 
`timetoken 14915504189961350`

It's happening on Simulator
MacOS Sierra 10.12.4

Xcode 8.3.1
iOS 10.3.1
iPhone 5

Update

The issue doesnt appear on iPhone 7

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace?

Comment: I am bit new to xcode. I have added more info. How can I share the full stacktrace?

Comment: What is the value of `timetoken`? Where does the error occur? Mac/iOS device/Simulator? 32-bit or 64-bit platform?

Comment: Which device are you simulating?

Comment: Added all information in the main post. Thanks for your help Martin.

Comment: if `timetoken` is 64 bit, do you think dividing it by 1000 makes it fit into 32 bit memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iPhone 5 is a 32-bit device, which means that [`Int` is a 32-bit
integer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/int), and the result of `timetoken / 10000` does not fit into an
`Int`. In contrast to some other programming languages, an integer overflow is a fatal runtime error in Swift (which is good, because otherwise
you would just get a wrong result).

I would suggest to convert the value to a `TimeInterval` instead 
(which is a floating point type, actually just a type alias for `Double`) and then call

```
public func moment(_ seconds: TimeInterval) -> Moment
```

instead of

```
public func moment(_ milliseconds: Int) -> Moment
```